# Polymorphic Datastructures Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection, data-structures, polymorphism

I'm attempting to use a generic type given on the fly to my method as the type for a given data structure similar to a map in function, but that uses only one class on declaration. It's more like an ArrayList with keys. So, what I'm attempting to do is:

```
private final ArrayList<T extends Object> findGroup(final String key, final String classType)
{
     Class<?> c = Class.forName(classType);
     ArrayList<c.class> listOfStuff = new ArrayList<>();

     return listOfStuff;
 }
```

The error I am getting occurs on the .class call.
I have tried c.getClass(), as well as making another Class object from c.class just to see if it works, but couldn't get it working.

Is there some preferred method for this?

Yes, I know that some of this tends to be a bit processing heavy, but I need it for what I'm doing.

Comment: Why not pass a `Class` object as parameter instead of `String`?

Comment: Due to type erasure, that wouldn't actually do anything.

Comment: _but I need it for what I'm doing._ What is that exactly?

Comment: `T extends Object` can simply be replaced by `?`.

Comment: This is one small part of the method. This is accompanied by another method, which together are used for getting data of a specified type from a service. I just shortened T extends Object to T, instead of ?.

Comment: I just shortened T extends Object to T, instead of ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the class object itself is known at compile time, it can be done as follows:

```
private final <T> List<T> findGroup(final String key, final Class<T> type)
{
    ArrayList<T> listOfStuff = new ArrayList<T>();

    // TODO: fill listOfStuff here (e.g. using key and type)

    return listOfStuff;
}
```

If you have to load the class at runtime based on a String, it is pointless to use generics here, because the method that calls `findGroup` is itself not aware of the actual type of the `List` at compile time. So you can only assign the result of `findGroup` to a `List<?>`. Hence why use generics then?

(Note that in java, generics are mainly for ensuring type safety at compile time. At runtime, there is no difference between a `List<String>` and a `List<Integer>` because type information gets erased when the code gets compiled).

Comment: Just wondering, the type variable doesn't seem to be used in your code. Did you mean to use it? This solution does seem to work a lot better, I'm just trying to figure out that part that you added.

Comment: In fact, you do not need the type argument to create the ArrayList, but I assume that the method does more than just creating a collection and needs the actual type of it. As the generic type parameter gets erased and is not available at runtime, you'll need a 'real' parameter for that.

Comment: That's the whole purpose it served, so I'll be taking that one out. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) will prevent such a thing from working. Basically, you cannot initialize a generic with a type known only at runtime, since the JVM has no knowledge about generic-types. Hence, the type must be available at compile time.